# Android Icon meaning

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean

I have an RCA tablet with Jelly Bean 4.2.  When I power on the tablet, the start up screen comes up, then the screen goes black and then the jelly bean android comes onto screen, laying on its back with a red triangle that has an exclamation point inside sitting on top of the android.  I cannot get into the tablet at all.  Does anyone know what the icon means?

Comment: "Andy out-of-order". Guess its stomach is open, too. He needs repair. Not necessarily the hardware. Maybe you [edit] your question and let us know what the last things were you did before this happened? That might give us an idea.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Android recovery image]
<sub>(source: [howtogeek.com](https://cdn.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/android-recovery-mode.jpg))</sub>

If you are getting this screen, that means your Android has booted into "recovery mode".